# How to pass a parameter to function which is in onclick and the onclick is in high ordered map. Does anyone know?

Tags: javascript

```js
const generateBtns = (item) => {
    let paginationBtnsDiv = document.querySelector(".paginationBtnsDiv");
    let numArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        numArray.push(i + 1);
    }

    let paginationResult = numArray.map(
        (num) => `<button onclick="onPageClick(item)" class="pages">${num} 
        </button>`
    );

    paginationBtnsDiv.innerHTML = paginationResult.join("");
};
```

This is my code. So I have button in map which has an onclick and I need to pass an argument to onclick function. Giving add event listener to class of buttons will not work because these buttons will be added later by clicking another button.

Comment: Did you try defining `onPageClick` function here? IMO it will work.

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet with tools `<>` please?

Comment: // on pagination button click
const onPageClick = (item) => {
  let uls = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
  let arrUls = Array.prototype.slice.call(uls);
  arrUls.forEach((sibling) => {
    sibling.style.display = "none";
  });
};

Comment: Please don't post that as a comment, but edit your question and add information there, nicely formatted. BTW, it seems that `onPageClick` does not actually *use* the argument `item`...

Comment: What is `item`? Is it a number, a string, ...?

Comment: item is <LI> created by document create element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to use `document.createElement` and then `addEventListener`:

```
const generateBtns = (item) => {
  let paginationBtnsDiv = document.querySelector(".paginationBtnsDiv");
  paginationBtnsDiv.innerHTML = "";
  for (let num = 1; num <= pageCount; num++) {
     let button = document.createElement("button");
     button.textContent = num;
     button.className = "pages";
     button.addEventListener("click", () => onPageClick(item));
     paginationBtnsDiv.appendChild(button);
  }
};
```